# Multiple table associated Form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I'm stuck with my ruby on rails project. I'm using rails 3.2

I manage to create checkboxes for skills in the human form but I can't work out how to create a form input which can change the "for_work" boolean value in the human_skills table.

So my goals is when a user create a new or edit a human they can select the skills and determine if the skills is for work or not (a boolean value).

Thanks so much in advance!

```
Here is my Human form code

    = semantic_form_for @human do |f|
    = f.input :name 
    = f.input :skills , :as => :check_boxes,
```

Database design

**skills** - id, name

**human_skills** - id, skills_id, human_id, for_work

**humans** - id, name

Here is my model code:

```
class Human < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :human_skills;
  has_many :skills, :through => :human_skills

class HumanSkill< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :human_skills;
    belongs_to :human;

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :human_skills;
  has_many :human, :through => :human_skills
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you need to adjust your models a little bit to allow human to create skills, and then use fields_for to let the form_for helper know it is on another model.

```
class Human < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :human_skills;
  has_many :skills, :through => :human_skills

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills

class HumanSkill< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :human_skills;
    belongs_to :human;

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :human_skills;
  has_many :human, :through => :human_skills
```

and the form

```
 = semantic_form_for @human do |f|
    = f.input :name 
    = fields_for @human.skills do |h_skills|
      = h_skills.checkbox :skills
```

Resources to check out to answer your question: Accepts Nested Attributes = [Accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)Fields For documentation:[Fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)
Nested Form video [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)